# Custom UIViewController with private view

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have a custom uiviewcontroller which extends uiviewcontroller. I want to prevent other viewcontroller to add my custom uiviewcontroller's view as a subview. How can do that with objective c?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Also, have you considered that `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController` work by embedding their children view controllers' views in their own view?